# Hide parsed variable from url bar

Tags: php, html

How can I make this url when passing a variable one form to another f

```
 localhost/haha/index.php/somethingupdate?id=mstr01
```

to this

```
 localhost/haha/index.php/somethingupdate
```

and I can still use the passed variable?
Can anyone help me with this, I'd much appreciate any help.

Comment: use POST or store it in cookie or session

Comment: you cant use a non existent variable, how about post or sessions?

Comment: You can't.  There are no "invisible" parts of an URL.  In the future, please use proper capitalization when you write your questions.

Comment: Use POST method to parse a data and if you want to access further then use cookie or session .

Comment: Sundar & Dagon : How?

Comment: Robert : thanks.i will in my next post.

Comment: This is how im parsing it (its in a Table) "<td><a href="http://localhost/haha/index.php/test/deletesomething?id=<? echo $row[0];?>">Delete</a></td>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your .htaccess file to redirect all requests to index.php, and in the index.php file you will have a controller which will handle all requests.

Example:

`routing.php` for PHP development server

```
<?php
   if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
     return false; // serve the requested resource as-is.
   } else {
     include_once 'index.php';
   }
?>
```

`.htaccess` file for apache web server

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/web/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /web/index.php
```

`controller.php` : A query-string controller

```
<?php 

/*
 * Page Controller
 * Decodes query string and loads page
 */

$qs=array_reverse(explode('/',parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
foreach ($qs as $key=>$value) $qs[$key] = urldecode(htmlspecialchars($value));
$this->controller = $qs[0];
switch ($this->controller) {
    case "somethingupdate":
        #$this->area = $qs[1];
        #if ($this->area=="home") {
        #   include("pages/home.php");
        #} else {
        #   include("pages/{$this->area}/home.php");
        #}
        break;
    case "somethingelse":
        #$this->cat = $qs[1];
        #$this->area = $qs[2];
        #if ($this->cat=="static") {
        #   include("pages/{$this->area}/home.php");
        #} else {
        #echo "Err.404 - Page not found (area:{$this->area}; cat:{$this->cat}.";
        #}
        break;
    default:
        $this->area = "home";
        include("pages/{$this->area}/home.php");
        break;
}?>
```

Then in your `index.php` file you include the `controller.php` where you want to display the page content.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use hidden field to pass variable

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="mstr01" />
```

Answer (score 1):

change your form method to POST and use the $_POST variable instead of the $_GET variable, and you will not see the variables at the end of the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use a client side solution

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", window.location);
```

but you should remove all characters after ? by replacing with space in window.location

for example x.com?id=10 should be x.com